# Unable to Upgrade/Downgrade Google Android in-app subscriptions

Tags: android, android-billing

I am facing a problem with the Trivial Drive app sample by Google.
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive

My problem is that every time I try to Upgrade/Downgrade a subscription, I always receive the error from Google: [DF-RPC-01].

When instead I try to purchase a brand new subscription from scratch, everything works properly.

Anyone that has the same problem?

I basically cannot have any upgrade/downgrade mechanism up and running. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: any luck with this, I'm facing the same issue?

Comment: No unfortunately.i moved away from Android dev, so it is not really an issue for me anymore.